# Neither load front end nor back-end in Magento 2.2.3

Tags: php, windows, magento, web, magento2.2

I have installed Magento-2.2.3 in windows personal computer and after the installation it loaded first time well but after that it is not responding since an hour.  Actually, I am new to Magento and anybody can tell about this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Follow the below points this may help you.**

1. enable all cache may help you. Full page cache .
2. MySQL 5.6 has some memory issues where a defaul config will use
   about 500mb of ram, to fix set performance_schema = off in your
   my.cnf and restart MySQL. Also make sure you have opcache turned on
   and set to at least 64mb of ram and 10000 files cached, preferable
   128mb. If you tune your config you can run on a 512mb vps but it's
   tricky and you won't have enough ram for fpc on varnish and reddis
   sessions. 1 gb vps with the above MySQL fix should work like a champ
   out of the box on a vps.
3. There are lots of potential reasons why, but the most common is
   around file system performance. In non-production mode especially,
   we hit the disk pretty hard (lots of different files). E.g. in
   developer mode we generate files on the fly (CSS etc). But without
   more details (PHP version? using Vagrant? VM? Docker? OS? Memory? is
   machine thrashing? etc), it is pretty hard to suggest something. Its
   certainly not taking any where near that long on my laptop. Can you
   provide any information about your setup? (But my first
   investigation would be around I/O performance - for example using
   Docker/VirtualBox with file syncing back to Windows is a dog -
   because the file syncing is very slow.)